# ViewPager, TabHost and Fragments from android.support.v4. All together doesn't work

Tags: android, android-tabhost, fragment, android-viewpager

I decided to create some small library which create awesome menu using ViewPager, Tabhost and FragmentActivity. So I have 3 small classes:

1. Draw menu (drawing all xml things)

   ```
   public class DrawAMKMenu extends FragmentActivity {

   protected LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
   protected static TabHost mTabHost;
   protected static Context mContext;
   protected ViewPager mViewPager;
   protected RelativeLayout mMenuBar;
   protected Resources res;
   protected int screenwidth;

   protected Drawable ThumbResource = null;
   protected Drawable menuBg = null;
   protected TabWidget tw;



   /**
    * constructor
    * @param c
    * @param main_layout
    */
   protected DrawAMKMenu(FragmentActivity fa, LinearLayout main_layout){
       mContext = fa.getApplicationContext();
       mLinearLayout = main_layout;
       res = fa.getResources();
       Display display = fa.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
       screenwidth = display.getWidth();

   }

   /**
    *Draw main LinearLayout 
    */
   protected void DrawMenu()
   {
       mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
       mLinearLayout.setBaselineAligned(true);
       mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
       mLinearLayout.addView(createTabHost());
   }
   /**
    * @return TabHost
    * draw the TabHost view
    */
   protected TabHost createTabHost(){

       mTabHost = new TabHost(mContext);
       mTabHost.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


       mTabHost.addView(createTabContentLayout());
       mTabHost.addView(createViewPager());
       mTabHost.addView(createMenuBar());  

       mTabHost.setTag("TabHost");
       SetupTabs(mTabHost);



       return mTabHost;
   }
   /**
    * Create FrameLayout for Content
    * @return FrameLayout
    */
   protected FrameLayout createTabContentLayout(){
       /*Frame layout for Content*/
       FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(mContext); 
       fl.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0,1));
       fl.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
       /*------------------------*/
       return fl;
   }

   /**
    * @return ViewPager
    * draw ViewPager element
    */
   protected ViewPager createViewPager(){
       mViewPager = new ViewPager(mContext);
       mViewPager.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1));
       mViewPager.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
       mViewPager.setTag("viewpager");
       return mViewPager;
   }  

   /**
    * @return RelativeLayout
    * draw Menu bar 
    */
   protected RelativeLayout createMenuBar(){
       /* Layout for Menu Bar */
       mMenuBar = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
       mMenuBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       //mMenuBar.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

       /* ------------------ */

       /* Tab Widget*/
       tw =  new TabWidget(mContext);
       tw.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0));
       tw.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

       tw.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
       if(menuBg != null)
           tw.setBackgroundDrawable(menuBg);
       /*-----------*/

       /* Scroll bar for menu */
       HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(mContext);
       hsv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0));
       hsv.setScrollBarStyle(View.GONE);
       hsv.setFillViewport(true);
       /* ----------------- */

       //add tabWidget to HorizontalScrollView
       hsv.addView(tw);

       /*Seek Bar*/
       SeekBar sb = new SeekBar(mContext);
       sb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       sb.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
       sb.setProgressDrawable(res.getDrawable(android.R.id.empty));

       if(ThumbResource!=null)
           sb.setThumb(ThumbResource);
       else
           sb.setThumb(res.getDrawable(android.R.id.empty));
       /*-------*/


       /*Frame layout for SeekBar*/
       FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(mContext);
       fl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       fl.addView(sb);
       /*------------------------*/


       mMenuBar.addView(hsv);
       mMenuBar.addView(fl);
       return mMenuBar;

   }

   /**
    * Delete bottom strip from tabhost
    * @param tabHost
    */
   protected void SetupTabs(TabHost tabHost) {

       Field mBottomLeftStrip;
       Field mBottomRightStrip;

       try {
           mBottomLeftStrip = tw.getClass().getDeclaredField("mBottomLeftStrip");
           mBottomRightStrip = tw.getClass().getDeclaredField("mBottomRightStrip");

           if (!mBottomLeftStrip.isAccessible()) {
               mBottomLeftStrip.setAccessible(true);
           }

           if (!mBottomRightStrip.isAccessible()) {
               mBottomRightStrip.setAccessible(true);
           }

           mBottomLeftStrip.set(tw,  res.getDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
           mBottomRightStrip.set(tw, res.getDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

       } 
       catch (java.lang.NoSuchFieldException e) {
           // possibly 2.2
           try {
               Method stripEnabled = tw.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setStripEnabled", boolean.class);
               stripEnabled.invoke(tw, false);
           } 
           catch (Exception e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
       } 
       catch (Exception e) {}
   }



   }
   ```
2. PagerAdapter class

   ```
   public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 

   private List<Fragment> pFragments;

   /**
    * @param fm
    * @param fragments
    */
   public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fr) {
       super(fm);
       this.pFragments = fr;
   }

   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
    */
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       return this.pFragments.get(position);
   }

   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
    */
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return this.pFragments.size();
   }
   }
   ```
3. Create menu class.

public  class AMKMenu extends DrawAMKMenu implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

```
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private Vector<Fragment> fragments;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private FragmentActivity mFragmentActivity;
private static HashMap<Integer, Class<?>> TabsClass;
private static HashMap<Integer, String> TabsTabName;
private static HashMap<Integer, Drawable> TabsIcon;


/**
 * CONSTRUCTOR
 * Create AMKMenu object to setup settings and 
 * also initialize menu 
 * @param c
 * @param main_layout
 * @param fm 
 * @param screenWidth
 */
public AMKMenu(FragmentActivity fa, LinearLayout main_layout) {
    super(fa, main_layout);
    mFragmentActivity = fa;
    mFragmentManager = fa.getSupportFragmentManager();
    TabsClass = new HashMap<Integer, Class<?>>();
    TabsTabName = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    TabsIcon = new HashMap<Integer, Drawable>();

}


/**
 * Final method to create menu
 * Use it after you setup all settings
 */
public void createMenu(){
    super.DrawMenu();
    initializeTabHost();
    intializeViewPager();

}
/**
 * A simple factory that returns dummy views to the Tabhost
 * @author Gavryschuk Anatoliy V.
 */
public class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context fContext;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        fContext = context;
    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
     */
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(fContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }

}
/**
 * Initialize ViewPager
 */
protected void intializeViewPager() {
    fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    if(getTabsClass().size()>0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<getTabsClass().size();i++)
        {
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(mFragmentActivity, getTabsClass(i).getName()));
        }
    }

    setPagerAdapter(new PagerAdapter (mFragmentManager, fragments));
    mViewPager.setAdapter(getPagerAdapter());
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
/**
 * Initialize the Tab Host
 */
protected void initializeTabHost() {
    if(getTabsClass().size()>0)
    {

        TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) mLinearLayout.findViewWithTag("TabHost");
        mTabHost.setup();
        for(int i=0;i<getTabsClass().size();i++)
        {
            TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getTabsTabName(i));
            tabSpec.setIndicator(getTabsTabName(i), getTabsIcon(i));
            tabSpec.setContent(new TabFactory(mFragmentActivity));
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        }

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        for(int i=0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            //mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(65,65));
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(0);
        }


        //  mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }else
        return;
}...
}
```

after I use this library in this way

```
AMKMenu menu = new AMKMenu(this, (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout));

    menu.setMenuBg(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_bg));
    menu.setCursor(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_cursor));

    menu.AddTab(Tab1Fragment.class, "tab1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f_icon));
    menu.AddTab(Tab2Fragment.class, "tab2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s_icon));
    menu.AddTab(Tab3Fragment.class, "tab3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t_icon)); 
    menu.createMenu();
```

I get error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No new found for id for fragment

The problem is in intializeViewPager() method in AMKMenu class.

Please Somebody (Android guru)  help me what do I do wrong?
I hope I explained everything clear.

Comment: Your class cannot get reference from R.id.main_layout try to use your own/another layout.

Comment: I'm not sure that it solve my problem as if I don't use intializeViewPager() method -  TabHost works great. So my class do get reference from R.id.main_layout

Answer (score 3):

Hear is my solution for the (Tabs + Fragment + ViewPager) it is works for me as i wanted, hope that works for you as well

hear is the xml file

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_details"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4.3" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

hear is the code for MainActivity.java I'll post relevant code only so you'll have to manage it

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        DialogInterface.OnDismissListener, TabDataResponder {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        artistTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText(
                R.string.tab_name_artist);
        albumTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText(
                R.string.tab_name_album);
        songTab = getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText(
                R.string.tab_name_songs);

        map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FrameLayout deatil = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_details);
        mDualPane = (deatil != null) && (deatil.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, getSupportActionBar(), mViewPager);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            flag = true;
            index = savedInstanceState.getInt("index");
        }

        setUpTabView();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("index", getSupportActionBar()
                .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    private void setUpTabView() {
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(artistTab, ArtistFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(albumTab, AlbumFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(songTab, SongFragment.class, null);
        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(index);
    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
            ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, ActionBar.TabListener {

        private FragmentActivity mContext;
        private ActionBar mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;

        private final ArrayList<String> mTabs = new ArrayList<String>();
        private TabDataResponder responder;

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ActionBar actionBar,
                ViewPager pager) {

            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = actionBar;
            mViewPager = pager;

            // TabDataResponder is an interface which is implemented in MainActivity
            // You can find implementation @ the last

            responder = (TabDataResponder) activity;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

            //I have used map to save state of the fragment
            map.put(SongFragment.TYPE_FRAGMENT.trim(), 0);
            map.put(AlbumFragment.TYPE_FRAGMENT.trim(), 0);
            map.put(ArtistFragment.TYPE_FRAGMENT.trim(), 0);
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            mTabs.add(clss.getName());
            // mArgs.add(args);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab.setTabListener(this));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return Fragment
                    .instantiate(mContext, mTabs.get(position), /*
                                                                 * mArgs.get(
                                                                 * position)
                                                                 */null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.i(TAG, "PageSelected....");
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ScrollSateChanged....");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            String a = null;
            if (mDualPane) {
                a = mTabs.get(tab.getPosition());
                responder.loadData(a, map.get(a));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Tab is released now....");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        setUpTabView();

    }
//This interface must be call from fragment class 
//@ the time of event you want to show detail 
// pass the class name in the type argument using class.getName() method
    @Override
    public void loadData(String type, int index) {
        DetailFragment viewer = (DetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_details);
        if (mDualPane) {
            if (viewer == null || viewer.getShownIndex() != index
                    || viewer.getTypeFragment() != type) {

                DetailFragment df = DetailFragment.newInstance(index, type);
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_details, df)
                        .setTransition(
                                FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                        .commit();
                map.put(type.trim(), index);

            }

        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", index);
            intent.putExtra("type", type);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**and hear is how i deal with detail fragment not very efficient but kind of working**

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment{

    public static DetailFragment newInstance(int index, String  TYPE_FRAGMENT) {
        DetailFragment f = new DetailFragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        args.putString("type", TYPE_FRAGMENT);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }



    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
    }

    public String getTypeFragment(){
        String a = getArguments().getString("type");
        return a;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //template is blank layout
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.template, container, false);
        if(getTypeFragment().equals(ArtistFragment.TYPE_FRAGMENT)){
            view = null;
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artist_details, container, false);
            //....

        }
        else if(getTypeFragment().equals(AlbumFragment.TYPE_FRAGMENT)){

            //do's for album fragment
        }
        else if(getTypeFragment().equals(SongFragment.TYPE_FRAGMENT)){
            //do's for song fragment
        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

***do not save the state of tab in their individual fragment it will conflict, we are already doing it hear***

Hope It Helps

Comment: I have it works if I use xml layout..... but the task is to create library(it will be jar file when I finish it). So I should realize it only with Java. And when I try to do it - I get error. But I will try your solution to convert in Java. Thanks in advance.